# How do you set a background image on every page of a PDF in iTextSharp?

Tags: image, pdf, background, itext

When creating a PDF in iTextSharp, how do you set an image as the background of every page?

I have tried several methods, and every one only puts the image on one page, or doesn't work at all.

I am not manually creating new pages in the PDF, but rather adding text that overflows to the next page.

```
        Dim document As Document = New Document()

        Dim writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, m)

        Dim imagepath As String = context.Server.MapPath("img.png")
        Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)

        writer.PageEvent = New pdfPageEvents(image)

.
.
.

Public Class pdfPageEvents
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper

    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image

    Public Sub New(ByVal backgroundImage As iTextSharp.text.Image)
        image = backgroundImage
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As PdfWriter, ByVal doc As Document)
        writer.Add(image)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: PDF doesn't have a concept of "background images", only just "images". If you want to simulate a background image you can just place an image using the raw `PdfContentByte` object and then drawing text on top of that. You could also instead try using a `PdfPTable` and cell events to simulate the above, see this for a Java version that you should be able to convert to .Net pretty easily. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3254450/231316

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add image background to pdf for every page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812955/how-to-add-image-background-to-pdf-for-every-page); if the examples I referred to in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812955/how-to-add-image-background-to-pdf-for-every-page/14813581#14813581) to that question don't work for you, explain your issues in detail.

Comment: @mlk yes, that's one of the methods I tried. In fact I was looking at that same post. I created a class that inherits PdfPageEventHelper containing the OnStartPage event. The PDF I was creating was two pages long. I even stepped through the code and saw the line where it was adding the image being executed twice, but there was no background image at all. I added some code to the main post to show what I did.

Comment: Never mind. I was adding it to the PdfWriter like you said. When I changed it and added it to the document instead, it worked fine.

Comment: `OnStartPage` is not meant for adding content (the page is only in the process of being prepared, it's not yet ready), and the document is not meant to be added to either.